# How can I make a link in firefox extension panel, to open in browser window / tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So I am developing my first firefox addon and I have a simple panel which contains some content and a link. When I click on the link, link is opened in the panel itself. I want to be able to open this link in firefox tab or window. I tried searching mozdev documentation but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either add a `target` attribute to your links (as `_blank` if you want to open a new tab every time); or intercept any `click` you do in the panel's document, and then send a message to your add-on code, to open a tab. Something like:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", event => {
  let a = event.target.closest("a");

  if (a && a.href) {
    // replace `self` with `addon` if it's a trusted document and
    // it's not a `contentScriptFile`
    self.port.emit("open-link", a.href);
  }
});
```

Then in your `index.js` or `main.js`, you'll have something like:

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

let panel = Panel({ /* ... your panel ... */ });

panel.port.on("open-link", uri => tabs.open(uri));
```

Comment: it says missing ";" before statetment " let a = event.target.closest("a");",. I am not sure about the correct syntax in this piece of code.

Comment: It's probably depends from which version of javascript you're using. If you're in content script, should be fine. Otherwise, `let` won't be recognized unless you use `type="text/javascript;version=1.8`. You can also replace `let` with `var`, in this context.

Comment: thanks it worked! it also needed to add the `event.preventDefault();` instruction to stop the link open in the panel.